# I have a basic CSS questions about stretching a shape across the width of a browser

Tags: html, css

I have a basic CSS questions about stretching a shape across the width of a browser.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40MCt.png)

I want to place the rectangle between the two triangles.

This is my HTML:

```
    <div id="monitor_top_left"></div>
    <div id="monitor_top_middle"></div>
    <div id="monitor_top_right"></div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
    #monitor_top_left {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-bottom: 60px solid #AFA995;
        border-left: 100px solid #5C5A4D;
        float: left;
    }
    #monitor_top_middle {
        width: 100%;        /* I need to stretch across the page */
        height: 60px;
        background: #AFA995;
        float: left;
    }
    #monitor_top_right {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-bottom: 60px solid #AFA995;
        border-right: 100px solid #5C5A4D;
        float: right;
    }
    .monitor_outer {
        clear: both;
    }
```

I'm having issues with my float properties, getting the rectangle between the triangles. I need the rectangle to be fluid for a responsive design.

Comment: do you have screenshot how it should look ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can float them all to the left and assign proper widths to them:

```
#monitor_top_left {
    width: calc(15% -100px); /* consider the border */
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 60px solid #AFA995;
    border-left: 100px solid #5C5A4D;
    float: left;
}
#monitor_top_middle {
    width: 70%;        /* I need to stretch across the page */
    height: 60px;
    background: #AFA995;
    float: left;
}
#monitor_top_right {
    width: calc(15% - 100px); /* consider the border */
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 60px solid #AFA995;
    border-right: 100px solid #5C5A4D;
    float: left;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/9aumgL0q/2/

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm in the beginning stages of HTML as you may have guessed, I didn't dawn on me that I could do the "100% - 200px" as the middle width. That's my lesson for today.

Comment: Glad to help, calc with consider the 100px per border.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to modify the width of `#monitor_top_middle`

```
#monitor_top_middle {
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
    /* I need to stretch across the page */
    height: 60px;
    background: #AFA995;
    float: left;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9aumgL0q/2/

Comment: Thank you. This was simple I'm sure, but something I needed.

Comment: glad this works for you ( don't forget to mark the question as answered :P )